# What can be concluded regarding the angles of $\triangle PQR$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question:**

> $PQR$ is a triangle. The area of a square of side $QR$ is equal to that of a rectangle whose length is $PR$ and breadth is $RS$ where $S$ is a point on $PR$ such that $QS \perp PR$. What can be concluded regarding the angles of $\triangle PQR$?
> A) $\angle P>90^\circ\qquad$  B) $\angle Q>90^\circ\qquad$  C) $\angle R>90^\circ\qquad$  D) None of these

I couldn't do this as I was unable to form a rectangle that looks like one but the way question is put I was getting something which was not a rectangle. We are given that the breadth of the rectangle is $RS$ which seems counter-intuitive to me.

Please help.

Comment: Is there any further info regarding what we're supposed to find out about the angles? As it is right now, the question seems ambiguous. The only thing I could deduce so far is that $∠Q > ∠P$.

Comment: @Hersh I'm really sorry, I have added that too.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satzgruppe_des_Pythagoras#Kathetensatz_des_Euklid (sorry, I haven't found this in English).

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Area of square $QRIJ=$ Area of rectangle $PRGH$
$$p^2=x(x+y)$$
that satisfies power of the point $R$

$QR$ is tangent to a circle

$QS \perp PR$ ,since $\angle S=90^o$ ($\angle $ insemicircle)

$\angle PQR=90^o$ ($\text{diameter} \perp \text{tangent}$)

Comment: Kindly pardon me as I forgot to add something in the question. Kindly check the edited question. Thank you.

Comment: @inanimatebeing - It is a right triangle with $\angle Q=90^o$, then answer is none of them.